# Error of universal Reference on Function Template

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I am trying to write a function template that takes a universal reference as parameter so it can accept both lvalue reference and rvalue reference.

When I write this:

```
template <typename Type>
concept is_number = std::integral<Type> || std::floating_point<Type>;

template <typename Type1, typename Type2>
    requires is_number<Type1> && is_number<Type2>
[[nodiscard]] inline auto add(Type1&& num1, Type2&& num2) noexcept
{
    return num1 + num2;
}

const std::int64_t num1 { 50 };
const double num2 { 30.6 };

std::cout << add(num1, num2) << std::endl;
```

The code works as expected. The add() function template successfully deduced as

```
[[nodiscard]] inline double add(const std::int64_t& num1, const double& num2);
```

However, when I try this code:

```
template <typename Type>
    requires is_number<Type>
[[nodiscard]] inline auto absolute(Type&& number) noexcept
{
    return number < 0 ? -(number) : number;
}

const double num3 { -12.5 };

std::cout << absolute(num3) << std::endl;   // Compiler warns: no matching overloaded function found
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: "*The code works as expected.*"  This is *not* how it should be. First of all, `is_number<Type1> & is_number<Type2>` uses bitwise AND instead of logical AND. In addition, `Type1` is deduced as `const std::int64_t&` in your example, which is a reference type and does not satisfy `std::integral`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 The bitwise & is a typo, I do apologize.

Comment: You need to use `remove_reference_t` to remove the reference of deduced type: `requires is_number<std::remove_reference_t<Type>>`.

Comment: `requires is_number<std::remove_cvref_t<Type>>`

Comment: @康桓瑋 Thank you so much ! Just out of curiosity, if this is the case, why does the add() function work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Universal references will make templates deduce reference types. This means that `Type` will probably be `std::int64_t&`. This is required for forwarding references to work.

Now your check is checking if the type is an integral or floating point. The type it receives is `std::int64_t&` or `float const&`, and both types are not numbers. They are references

To make it work you need to remove qualifiers when using your concept:

```
template <typename Type>
    requires is_number<std::remove_cvref_t<Type>>
[[nodiscard]] inline auto absolute(Type&& number) noexcept
{
    return number < 0 ? -(number) : number;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer ! I always thought Type deductions comes before everything, in which I thought std::int64_t will be deduced first, then the universal reference will deduce whether it is a lvalue or rvalue reference.

Comment: @TheLonesomeCoder There's only one deduction going on, and one type that `Type` would take. The way it is deduce may involve reference or constness if you use forwarding references.

Answer (score 4):

Removing [cv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) qualifiers and reference form your `is_number` concept allows `add` and `absolute` to work with const and references as well:

```
template <typename Type>
concept is_number = std::integral<std::remove_cvref_t<Type>> || 
                    std::floating_point<std::remove_cvref_t<Type>>;
```